# How to make mobile version hamburger menu button working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

I had an wordpress website and its mobile version hamburger menu is not working as I tried adding the script too. How to get that menu button working.

Below I had providing the link for the website which the menu is not working.

https://drisharikganesh.com/

Code:

```
// Events Listeners
hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
navItems.forEach((nav) => {
  nav.addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
});
```

Still its not working and where it should be added, please help me to get this working.

Comment: That hamburger on the UI is a <button> element. Are you sure you have a click event handler added to it in the code?

Comment: I guess no, I am new to this i have no idea. i just know its not working

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for the website you mentioned? If yes then check for "Responsive Menu" in HTML there you will find a button element. You need to add a click event listener to it.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and if you can update your question, you'll get more usable answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
document.querySelector(".navbar-toggle.tablet-responsive").addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelector(".navbar-collapse").classList.toggle("collapse")
})
</script>
```

Install "code snippets" plugin from plugins. Add this code to your footer area. If you have any problems, please search on google "how to add javascript code to footer with code snippets" or something similar. You should be good.

Comment: its working thanks for help but, there are sub menus in mobile are not working can you please help with that

Comment: The dropdown for sub menu in mobile devices were not working

Answer (score 0):

---

```
`burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')
rightnav = document.querySelector('.rightnav')
navList = document.querySelector('.nav-List')

burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    navbar.classList.toggle("h-nav-resp");
    navList.classList.toggle("v-class-resp");
     rightNav.classList.toggle("v-class-resp");
                                    `
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).